# How To Remotely Change the Content In umbraco using Apis

Tags: api, razor, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

Hello EveryOne I'm New To Umbraco I did Some Simple Umbraco Sites and Im good with so far Based on my Humble .Net background My Question is : How can i Remotely Change the Content of My umbraco form Other Pc or Something like that using Web service or APIs or what ever Im Looking foreword For a Good answer

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can create a webapi on top of your Umbraco instance. You'll have to implement the actions yourself.

See [this reference](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/) on how to implement it

Another option is installing [Umbraco Rest API](https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoRestApi). This will add functionality for managing content and media through a rest service. Haven't tried this plugin myself, so no clue if works in the current version.
Some additional information can be found [here](https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Implementation/Rest-Api/)

Comment: Hello , How can i instantiate  ContentService(); 
Keeps give a Error i want it to be like this

Var x = New ContentService();

Comment: ContentService is a singleton, you can access it through `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService`

Comment: Hello Friend 
How Can i publish it on the Enter net? 
i put my (IP Adresss) THEN //localhost:53711 
keeps on giving me Runtime Error 
iv made THe Custom Error Mode to Off in Web config Still the Same